Cursor jumps to the start or end of line when using the arrow in Windows 11
On my windows pc, on any line when I use the keyboard arrow left or arrow right keys to navigate any text, the cursor goes either to the start or the end of the line. No in between. If tried to look in windows typing settings and keyboard settings the see if there is a setting which is causing the issue.

What is your question?

I ended up answering my own question which was how to resolve the issue of the arrow keys skipping from the start of a line to the end.

Please don't edit the answer into your question. [su] is a question and answer site and answers should be separate from questions. Please read Can I answer my own question?
